# Как сделать текст на рамке, в качестве заголовка?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Примерно так выглядит в результате.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для таких групп есть HTML-тэг `fieldset`, а надпись устанавливается с помощью вложенного тэга `legend`.

```css
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #339dc7;
  /* Чтобы подстраивался под контент */
  display: inline-block;
}

legend {
  color: #339dc7;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Введите данные
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```